replace values of a column (but keep NA values) with list of other values python
I would like to start since I am looking for tips on how to tackle this issue, rather than specific code with an answer I have not provided any code, just my situation. Is this allowed? Or am I still required to provide some form of code? I am unsure on these guidelines so if this is not allowed please inform me and I will not do this next time :)
I have the following dataframe:



well
sample




A1
1


NaN
2


NaN
3


A2
1


NaN
2


A3
1


NaN
2


NaN
3



Is it possible to replace the values in the column 'well' (thus the A1, A2, A3 etc) with the values of a list?
I have made a list = [0,31,20] for example and need the well names replaced by this list or I need an extra column with the values of the list on the same row as the well name (thus other rows in the column need to stay NaN)
I have tried working with for example df.replace() where I tried using a dictionary in stead of list, or using the list but these approaches did not work.
I hope to obtain tips on how to tackle this issue (thus not specific codes with the answer, I am still learning python therefore tips could help me in the learning process rather than specific pieces of code with a solution)
To visualise below the two options I am searching for as final dataframe:
Option 1



well
sample




0
1


NaN
2


NaN
3


31
1


NaN
2


20
1


NaN
2


NaN
3



Or option 2:



well
sample
Position




A1
1
0


NaN
2
NaN


NaN
3
NaN


A2
1
31


NaN
2
NaN


A3
1
20


NaN
2
NaN


NaN
3
NaN



Thank you in advance for your help!

Please take the [tour] and see [ask]. "I hope to obtain tips on how to tackle this issue (thus not specific codes with the answer ...)". SO is about getting answers, not general "approach" tips. As per the basic logic in suggested duplicate, you can use df.loc[df['well'].notna(), 'well'] = [0, 31, 20]. So, Series.notna rather than Series.isnull, but the idea is the same. This assumes the list is the same size as the mask. For a new column, first add the new column with np.nan only and then apply.

To replace specific values you can use .replace or . map with a Dictionary. See this SO question

@ouroboros1 the difference is that I do not want to replace NaN values, only the actual values. In addition, thank you I did not know about that tour and I will look into that!

@user19077881 so replace specific values I tried using the dictionary approach however in the cases my samples went into the double digits (eg A12, it replaced it by 0, the value in my dictionary for A1) even though my dictionary did not say A12 is 0

@Soef: yes, that's why I added that you should use Series.notna rather than Series.isnull (or Series.isna, which is the same). Otherwise, it's the same, i.e.: you typically use df.loc for this.

@ouroboros1 also thank you your answer worked :) I am going to read into that solution how it works! Sorry, I did not understand that it was a change to that solution

Dictionary works for me. df['well'] = df['well'].map(my_dict).fillna(df['well'])
